# Folder.WellKnownFolderName is null in EWS Managed API and Exchange 2013

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server, managed-ews

Using EWS Managed API with Office 365 (ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1 profile). When calling Folder.FindFolders for a parent folder, I get Folder.WellKnownFolderName value as null for all returned Folder objects (including well-known folders like Inbox). Other values like .TotalCount are fine.

Folder.WellKnownFolderName doc in MSDN states it should work for Exchange2013 and higher and I believe Office 365 meets this criteria.

Also, if I connect to Exchange 2010 server and set ExchangeVersion.Exchange_2010 profile, .WellKnownFolderName throws an exception rather than returns null (this is the expected behavior). So (in my understanding), depending on the version, it should either throw an exception or return non-null value for a well-known folder like Inbox.

Am I missing something?

Or maybe I should use other means to determine system folders like Inbox, Sent Items, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That property isn't returned by default not matter what version your using you have to specify a propertyset and request that the server return that for you eg

```
        FolderView wkfView = new FolderView(1000);
        wkfView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        wkfView.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.WellKnownFolderName);

        service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, wkfView);
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding FolderSchema.WellKnownFolderName to PropertySet causes "Requested value 'clutter' was not found." ArgumentException during FindFolders call (I'm using Office 365 server). Any clues?

Comment: For me, it looks like there is a bug in Managed EWS API 2.2. It doesn't understand Clutter special mailbox type and crashes instead of just silently not setting any WellKnownFolderName for Clutter folder. Currently, this makes listing folders with well-known names in Office 365 account unusable, unless I'm missing something again..

Comment: I would suggest you try to compile the latest ews managed api from github https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api if that is a bug you should be able to fix it in the source (2.2 is very old at this point)

Comment: Thanks, the latest build from github works. However, it's strange that nuget's latest version is still 2.2. Our customers normally use nuget so my library (which they obtain from nuget either) has to use nuget's version of EWS api..

Comment: Yeah I don't know why Microsoft aren't maintaining the Nuget packages it causes a lot of grief of people

Comment: @GlenScales Yes this is indeed a version problem.